# Laravel function on a relationship returns call to undefined method

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm trying to apply a function to get value of a group, structure goes like:

- User

  - Group

    - GroupPermissions

What i have:

Model **User**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

 public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo("Group");
}
```

Model **Group** :

```
class Group extends Eloquent {

 public function GroupPermissions(){
    return $this->hasMany("GroupPermissions");
}
```

Model **GroupPermissions** :

```
class GroupPermissions extends Eloquent {

 public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo("Group");
}

public function getPermission($permission){
    return $this->first()->$permission;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getPermission()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupPermissions()` will return a collection as result. Not a single model. So you can't just call `getPermission()` on it.

You can either do it somewhat direct:

```
$group = Group::find(1);
$permission = $group->GroupPermissions()->first()->foo;
```

Or put the function inside the group model:

```
public function getPermission($permission){
    return $this->GroupPermissions()->first()->$permission;
}
```

Usage:

```
$group = Group::find(1);
$permission = $group->getPermission('foo');
```